# How to show the results of a program by entering something in input?

Tags: python, printing, zero

So, I have a program, which I am finishing but I apparently ran into a problem. In the program I have to make that whenever I enter a 0 in the input, the program will stop and print the results. Here's the program before I continue saying anything else:

```
import collections
students = collections.defaultdict(list)

while True:
    student = input("Enter a name: ").replace(" ","")
    if student == "0":
        print ("A zero has been entered(0)")
        break

    if not student.isalpha():
            print ("You've entered an invalid name. Try again.")
            continue

    while True:
        grade = input("Enter a grade: ").replace(" ","")
        if grade == "0":
            print ("A zero has been entered(0)")
            break

        if not grade.isdigit():
            print ("You've entered an invalid name. Try again.")
            continue

        grade = int(grade)
        if 1 <= grade <= 10:
            students[student].append(grade)
            break

for i, j in students.items():
    print ("NAME: ", i)
    print ("LIST OF GRADES: ", j)
    print ("AVERAGE: ", round(sum(j)/len(j),1))
```

I figured out a way how to make the program stop and post results after a 0 is entered in the `"Enter a name: "` part. This is what is printed out:

```
Enter a name: Stacy
Enter a grade: 8
Enter a name: 0
A zero has been entered(0)
NAME:  Stacy
LIST OF GRADES:  [8]
AVERAGE:  8.0
```

I need to do the same with the `"Enter a grade: "` part but if I try to make the program like it is now, this is what it prints out:

```
Enter a name: Stacy
Enter a grade: 0
A zero has been entered(0)
Enter a name:
```

**How do I make the program show results like it does when a 0 is entered in the name input?**

Answer (score 1):

In one of your inputs, check to see if the input is 0. If it is, make a call to `sys.exit`. This can be done anywhere, even when checking for the grade. Just make sure that you include both options then (a string 0 and an int 0). Also, the reason for why it was still saying `A zero has been entered(0)` is because you are only quitting out of one loop, and then continuing from the beginning basically.

```
# Be sure to import sys!

random_place = input("Whatever is here ")
if random_place == '0' or random_pace == 0:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Your program will exit then.

Comment: This would just exit the program without displaying the name, grade list, and average

Answer (score 0):

You should look into functions as they would save you a lot of hassle here, however here is a commented version of your code that will exit on either input being 0 and display the end message.

```python
import collections
students = collections.defaultdict(list)

while True: #combined while loops
    print ("Enter 0 for name or grade to exit") #you don't say how to exit
    student = input("Enter a name: ").replace(" ","")
    if student == "0":
        print ("A zero has been entered(0)")
        break
    grade = input("Enter a grade: ").replace(" ","")
    if grade == "0":
        print ("A zero has been entered(0)")
        break
    #can combined if student == 0 or grade == 0, but then both inputs must display

    if not student.isalpha() or not grade.isdigit():
        print ("You've entered an invalid name or grade. Try again.")
        #since these were the same message just combine them
        #can switch to too if statements if you want seperate messages
        #Also you might want to add a enter only alpha or digits for... message
        break

    grade = int(grade) 
    if 1 <= grade <= 10:
        students[student].append(grade)

for i, j in students.items():
    print ("NAME: ", i)
    print ("LIST OF GRADES: ", j)
    print ("AVERAGE: ", round(sum(j)/len(j),1))
```

Comment: If I would use your code, then it would be bad. Sorry. I really appreciate your help but, the problem is, the code still doesn't print the answers after putting in a 0 in grade, the name can be a digit (which cannot be) and when I enter a 5 in it and it said it was an invalid number.

Comment: @Acu What problems are you having? This code works based on your problem for python3 - you never specified which you were using but your code looks like python3. If this code still doesn't work you need to say specifically why and work with us to improve it based on your skill - else it is just me doing your homework.